# How to prevent unwanted variable assignment inside condition statement?

Tags: debugging, if-statement, conditional-statements, assignment-operator

Missing equal sign inside assignment (typing `=` instead of `==`) make unwanted assignment inside a condition statement. 
For example, consider the scenario below (this example is in C, but the question is valid also for interpreted code).

**CASE A:**

```
int g=1;

if ( g == 3 )
{
    printf("g is 3");   
}
else
{
    printf("g is not 3"); 
}

//this return: "g is not 3"
```

**CASE B:** *(typo: missing `=` inside condition)*

```
int g=1;

if ( g = 3 )
{
    printf("g is 3");   
}
else
{
    printf("g is not 3");
}

//this return: "g is 3" because of the assignment
```

Both the cases are formally correct, so the code will work but not as we want; and may be hard to debug.

How to prevent this situation? There is a solution that cover the interpreted code (for example javascript), apart static analyzers?

Comment: Most compilers can be configured to issue a warning when you do this.

Comment: case B will assign 3 to g then test g as a Boolean, as g is NOT false it will always be g is 3, but this isn't what was intended and assignment was not intended.  You could just use a macro to perform the test, passing g to the marco and using the macro in the condition.

Comment: Easiest solution:  configure your compiler to warn about any assignment in any conditional clause, treat them as errors, and never stuff the assignment into the conditional clause in the first place.  "Brevity of code" is not something you should have as a goal when writing code - **readable, understandable, and *maintainable*** code is the goal.  And that means not using bug-prone constructs, even if they're "legal code".

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, using an assignment inside a condition body for `if`, `while`, or `for` is perfectly valid C and is very often used intentionally.  For example, I often find myself using the following skeleton code to create a window when writing a Win32 API GUI:

```
if((hWnd = CreateWindowExW(...)) == NULL)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Window creation failed", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
    return GetLastError();
}
```

If the test is solely for equality and you want to avoid using the `=` operator accidentally, one thing you can do is get into the habit of putting the r-value on the left side of the operator, so that if you accidentally use `=`, it will produce a compilation error:

```
char *p = malloc(100000);
if(NULL == p)
{
    // handle null pointer
}
```

Obviously, this only works if at least one side of the comparison is an r-value or a `const` variable.

Comment: *The thing is, using an assignment inside a condition body for if, while, or for is perfectly valid C and is very often used intentionally.*  And stuffing the assignment into the if condition gains you absolutely nothing, and comes at the cost of potentially impossible-to-find bugs should you miss a set of parenthesis.  And how do you handle functions such as `fork()` that have three branches post-call?